# Chef Cookbook: service is not starting

Tags: service, jboss, chef-infra, cookbook

I have a problem with my JBoss-cookbook, the service is created correctly in /etc/init.d and can be started/stopped/restarted by using service start/stop/restart jboss, but it is not started after Chef finished deploying my infrastructure.

This is the part of my cookbook that creates the service.

```
template "jboss" do
  path "/etc/init.d/jboss"
  source "init_deb.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0755"
end

service "jboss" do
  supports :restart => true, :start => true, :stop => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end

execute 'wait for JBoss' do
  command 'sleep 5'
  action :nothing
end
```

Thanks and Regards,
Sascha

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I got it, it was some kind of race condition in my runlevel script, my Cookbook was perfectly fine.